# ruby name can't be blank error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

it may be a repeated question,but the previous answers doesn't help me

i got "name can't be blank", "mobile no cann't be blank" error while sign up the page, even though i filled up the name and mobile no

my routes.rb is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users
 namespace :api do
  resources :users, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
 end
```

my controller page

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    params.permit!
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user = User.new
    @user.name = params[:user][:name]
    @user.email = params[:user][:email]
    @user.mobile_no = params[:user][:mobile_no]
    @user.password = params[:user][:password]
    @user.valid?
    if@user.errors.blank?
        @user.save
    else
        render :action => "new"
    end
end

def update
    super
end
end
```

my view page is

```
 <h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:   registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :mobile_no %><br />
    <%= f.telephone_field :mobile_no, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

my model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    def users_params
    params.require(:users).permit(:name, :email, :mobile_no, :password)
    end
    validates :email,:name, :mobile_no :presence =>true
    validates_uniqueness_of :email
 end
```

what am i missing,... thanks in advance....

Comment: **Just a suggestion**: You can use `if @user.save` instead of `if @user.errors.blank?`. And when I faced such similar problem, I added `attribute_accessible` in the respective model. But, not sure why strong parameter didn't work form me as well

Comment: @fyodorios - I gave you an answer already. Have you tried changing your fields to text fields?

Comment: Your `form_for( resource` probably should be `form_for( @user` and drop the `as: resource_name`. They appear to be cut n paste default values, whereas the intention is to tie the form to the model you instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with my routes.rb

replaced the route, from

```
devise_for :users
```

to,

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

now, it's working fine,...

thanks guys for the response